# Swagger express sequelize

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm trying to set up a swagger, but I'm running into an error

```
Resolver error at paths./projects.post.parameters.0.schema.$ref
Could not resolve reference: #/models/Projects
```

Below is my project code
routes/projects.js
const Projects = require("../models").Projects;

```
module.exports = (app) => {
    /**
     * @swagger
     * /projects:
     *   post:
     *     tags:
     *       - Projects
     *     name: Create Project
     *     summary: Create Project
     *     consumes:
     *       - application/json
     *     parameters:
     *       - name: body
     *         in: body
     *         schema:
     *           $ref: '#/models/Projects'
     *           type: object
     *           properties:
     *             authorFirstName:
     *               type: string
     *             authorLastName:
     *               type: string
     *     responses:
     *       200:
     *         description: Project add successfully
     */
    app.post("/projects", (req, res) => {});
};
```

models/Projects.js

```
"use strict";
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Projects = sequelize.define("Projects", {
        authorFirstName: DataTypes.STRING,
        authorLastName: DataTypes.STRING
    });
    return Projects;
};
```

This is a test project for swagger configuration. I use node.js express and sequelize

Here is swagger

```
var swaggerDefinition = {
    info: {
        title: "TETS MySQL api",
        version: "1.0.0",
        description: "Endpotions"
    },
    host: "localhost:4000",
    basePath: "/",
    securityDefinitions: {
        bearerAuth: {
            type: "apiKey",
            name: "Authorization",
            schema: "bearer",
            in: "header"
        }
    }
};

const options = {
    swaggerDefinition,
    apis: ["./routes/*.js"]
};
const swaggerSpec = swaggerJSDoc(options);

app.get("/swagger.json", function(req, res) {
    res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    res.send(swaggerSpec);
});
app.use("/api-docs", swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerSpec));
```

Comment: Can you replace `'#/models/Projects'` with '#/definitions/Projects' and see if this fixes the issue?

Comment: Resolver error at paths./user/login.post.parameters.0.schema.$ref
Could not resolve reference: #/definitions/Projects